# How can I tokenize a CSV row on Android and include empty columns as empty strings?

Tags: android, string, csv, tokenize

I want to read a CSV file in Android, but for rows with some blank columns, CSV writes something like this:

```
,,,,ABC,,,d,mfcmf,fgt,
```

When I tokenize the above line I get `ABC` as the first string, when I need `""` (i.e. an empty string).

How can I tokenize CSV rows, but have blank columns show up in the results as empty strings?

```
First_column  = "";
Second_column = "";
Third_column  = "";
Forth_column  = "";
Fifth_column  = "ABC";
```

Comment: What does "consigative" mean?

Comment: oops spell mistack,The same character one after anather,Like AA BB etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own little parser or use a CSV library. To simply split the string on comma characters does not work if there are embedded commas in a field like here

```
a,1,"some , in string",12
```

One library that could be used in [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/)

Comment: i to do that i am very new bies in java.